# Insert statement issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, insert

I was using the statement

```
insert into foo select bar from foobar
```

it worked fine.

Then, one fine day, I changed it to:

```
insert into foo(bar) select bar from foobar
```

and now it doesn't work.

whats wrong with the second statement?

I want to know these things so I can decide if I have to be careful about this in future.

**EDIT**

Now that that is clear. I would like to know if the syntax is different for MSSQL and Oracle. Please help

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/toc.htm

Comment: @MozenRath in this case the syntax is the same for SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: @DennisTraub ok... basically i was getting an error on SQL Server for first statement, I changed it to second statement and it worked fine(That's why the the one fine day happened in my life). So I guess that is the real problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 possible syntax choices:

```
insert into foo
    select bar from foobar


insert into foo (column_name_of_foo)
    values (select bar from foobar)
```

If your foo table doesn't habe a bar column then you will get an error with your second syntax because you are naming the column in that you want to insert something.

With the first syntax you are not naming the column you are inserting into.

Answer (score 2):

When using the syntax in your second statement (`insert into table (column)`) you need to add the `values` keyword and the values themselves must be surrounded by parentheses:

```
insert into foo (bar[, bar2]) values (select bar[, bar2] from foobar)
```